# Polygon mask SVG doesn't load SVG in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

`

Hi, I wanted to make some nice landing page with tsparticles, but I have problem with it. It just display particles randomly, not in shape of an SVG. Can somebody help me with that

I tried adding domains to nextjs config, using local files. I dont really know what to do, so if anybody has an idea, it would really help me.
`

```
"use client";
import { useMantineTheme, useMantineColorScheme } from '@mantine/core';
import {Button} from "@mantine/core"
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import MainNavigation from './MainNavigation';
import { useCallback } from "react";
import Particles from "react-tsparticles";
import { loadFull } from "tsparticles";
import "pathseg";
import "../styles/globals.css";
import Head from 'next/head';
export default function TopSection(props) {

    const particlesInit = useCallback(async engine => {
      
      console.log(engine);
    
      await loadFull(engine);
  }, []);

  const particlesLoaded = useCallback(async container => {
   
      await console.log(container);
  }, []);
  if (process.browser) {
    require("pathseg");
  }
  
  return (
    <div style={{width: "100%", height: "100VH", display: "flex", flexDirection: "column"}}>
    <Head>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pathseg@1.2.0/pathseg.min.js" />
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tsparticles@1.18.3/dist/tsparticles.min.js" />
    </Head>
    <MainNavigation />
    <div>
    <Particles
            id="tsparticles"
            init={particlesInit}
            loaded={particlesLoaded}
            options={{
  detectRetina: false,
  interactivity: {
    detectsOn: "canvas",
    events: {
      onClick: {
        enable: false,
        mode: "push"
      },
      onDiv: {
        elementId: "repulse-div",
        enable: false,
        mode: "repulse"
      },
      onHover: {
        enable: true,
        mode: "bubble",
        parallax: {
          enable: false,
          force: 2,
          smooth: 10
        }
      },
      resize: true
    },
    modes: {
      bubble: {
        distance: 40,
        duration: 2,
        opacity: 8,
        size: 6,
        speed: 3
      },
      connect: {
        distance: 80,
        lineLinked: {
          opacity: 0.5
        },
        radius: 60
      },
      grab: {
        distance: 400,
        lineLinked: {
          opacity: 1
        }
      },
      push: {
        quantity: 4
      },
      remove: {
        quantity: 2
      },
      repulse: {
        distance: 200,
        duration: 0.4
      },
      slow: {
        active: false,
        radius: 0,
        factor: 1
      }
    }
  },
  particles: {
    color: {
      value: ["#4285f4", "#34A853", "#FBBC05", "#EA4335"]
    },
    lineLinked: {
      blink: false,
      color: "random",
      consent: false,
      distance: 40,
      enable: true,
      opacity: 0.8,
      width: 1
    },
    move: {
      attract: {
        enable: false,
        rotate: {
          x: 600,
          y: 1200
        }
      },
      bounce: false,
      direction: "none",
      enable: true,
      outMode: "bounce",
      random: false,
      speed: 1,
      straight: false
    },
    number: {
      density: {
        enable: false,
        area: 2000
      },
      limit: 0,
      value: 200
    },
    opacity: {
      animation: {
        enable: true,
        minimumValue: 0.3,
        speed: 2,
        sync: false
      },
      random: false,
      value: 0.8
    },
    shape: {
      character: {
        fill: false,
        font: "Verdana",
        style: "",
        value: "*",
        weight: "400"
      },
      image: {
        height: 800,
        replaceColor: true,
        src: "https://particles.js.org/images/github.svg",
        width: 800
      },
      polygon: {
        sides: 5
      },
      stroke: {
        color: "#000000",
        width: 0
      },
      type: "circle"
    },
    size: {
      animation: {
        enable: false,
        minimumValue: 0.1,
        speed: 40,
        sync: false
      },
      random: true,
      value: 1
    }
  },
  polygon: {
    draw: {
      enable: false,
      lineColor: "rgba(255,255,255,0.2)",
      lineWidth: 0.5
    },
    enable: true,
    move: {
      radius: 5
    },
    position: {
      x: 30,
      y: 10
    },
    inlineArrangement: "equidistant",
    scale: 10,
    type: "inline",
    url:
      "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b8/2021_Facebook_icon.svg"
  },
  background: {
    color: "white",
    image: "",
    position: "50% 50%",
    repeat: "no-repeat",
    size: "cover"
  }
}}
        />
    </div>
 
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not a Next.js or React issue. The configuration of the polygon mask feature was changed in v2. You need to change this piece:

```
inlineArrangement: "equidistant",
```

to this:

```
inline: {
    arrangement: "equidistant"
},
```